# A title or descriptive phrase for someone who likes to share

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, internet

I'm building a mobile app that has a series of achievements that may be awarded based on the users interaction. The app itself is an easter egg hunt.

One of the achievements is for sharing (via Facebook, Twitter, SMS etc).

What would be a good title or badge for someone who often shares or attempts to persuade friends to join them?

An example of a different achievement:

"Night Owl" - 10 Eggs collected between the hours of 9pm and 4am.

Comment: ... Philanthropist.

Comment: Following the format of Night Owl, ["Social Butterfly"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Butterfly) which is "a slang term for a person who is socially dynamic, networking, charismatic, and personally gregarious" may describe "someone who often shares [on social media sites] or attempts to persuade friends to join them". I've mostly heard that applied to females, though, so maybe something like Leader of the Pack is better.

Comment: Yeah we like "Social Butterfly"... It fits with the rest of the achievements. Thanks!

Comment: The **generous** one. *Magnanimous*, *big-hearted*, *lavish*?

Comment: Socialist.  It's a cute play on words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't find it in a dictionary, but...

> **publiciser/publicizer** (from the [verb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/publicize) form *bring to public notice; advertise*)

---

Here on StackExchange we have a badge for...

> [**publicist**](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/publicist) *- shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.*

...but that's [*especially a press agent or public-relations consultant*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/publicist?s=t) - "commercial" connotations that arguably don't fit too well with OP's (or indeed, SE's) contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Boastful, boaster, braggart, bragger, exhibitionist, showoff (show-off), hotshot, peacock, grandstander.

Answer (score 0):

'Not Pedestrian'.

To be 'pedestrian' is to be 'not interesting or unusual.'

'Not pedestrian' is to be exactly that--interesting and unusual.